# ¿Alguien sabe si hay algun programa que permita pasar codigo c a c++?

Tags: c++, c, dev-c++

Tengo un programa hecho en c y lo necesito pasar a c++. Saben si hay algun programa que me ayude en esto, no tengo muy clara la sintaxis de c++

Comment: Me gustaría que desarrollaras el contexto, ¿por que quieres hacer eso? ¿Que problema soluciona que el código sea C++ y no C?

Comment: En líneas generales, la mayor parte del código C es compatible con C++... no así a la inversa. ¿Has probado a compilarlo a ver si suena la flauta y  te compila?

Answer (score 2):

C++ es un lenguaje que extiende la sintaxis de C, o al menos así surgió.

En principio, si te atienes al lenguaje C estándar y no utilizas extensiones de uno u otro compilador, un compilador de C++ debería compilar tu código sin ningún problema.

Solo debes tener en cuenta que, por mera facilidad, en C++ los ficheros de código fuente suelen tener extensión `.cpp`, por lo que quizá te conviene copiar los ficheros de código fuente y cambiarles la extensión.

También, a pesar de que puedes incluir bibliotecas de C, es mejor idea incluir bibliotecas de C++. En tu código fuente, las bibliotecas estándar de C, como `stdio.h` son referenciadas sin la extensión `.h`, y anteponiendo una `c`.

Por lo tanto un código como:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Se transformaría en:

```
#include <cstdio>
```

Poco más, el lenguaje C++ es híbrido, por lo que puedes compilar un programa que no haga uso de ninguna clase, al estilo C.

Si quieres saber qué bibliotecas son estándar para realizar el cambio que he mencionado antes, tienes una lista [aquí](http://cplusplus.com/reference/), en la sección "C Library" del panel izquierdo. Ya vienen con el nombre de C++ indicado, y el nombre de C entre paréntesis.

**Edición**:

Como comentan algunos colegas, no todo código válido en C es válido en C++. Hay algunas diferencias importantes, pero en la mayoría de casos no te vas a topar con estas diferencias, o son muy fáciles de sortear con la ayuda del compilador.

Tienes más información sobre la compatibilidad entre C y C++ [aquí](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_of_C_and_C%2B%2B).

Comment: Actualmente hay características de C que no son compatibles con C++